# Python Mocking Callback

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am looking to try and unit test a certain design pattern and having some trouble getting things to work. Would greatly appreciate some help on this issue. Below is the basic idea around the code I want to test. I've tried a few different variations on patching and create_autospec but unable to get the callback to work correctly.

I would like to mock out the b.start() method to only just do the callback instead of all the logic.

Updated code with latest attempt. the callback method isn't getting bound.

A.py

```
import time
from B import B

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = None
        self.flag = True

    def start_b(self):
        self.b = self.create_b()
        self.b.callback = self.b_completed
        self.b.start()
        while self.flag:
            print("Waiting on Job Finish")
            time.sleep(1)

    def create_b(self):
        return B()

    def b_completed(self, b):
        self.flag = False
```

B.py

```
from threading import Thread

class B(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = None

    def run(self):
        # do some logic
        print("In B.run")
        self.callback(self)
```

tests/test_A.py

```
import unittest
from mock import mock
import A
import B

class ATestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(A.A, "create_b", autospec=True)
    def test_simple(self, mock_create_b):
        mock_create_b.side_effect = create_b_mock
        a = A.A()
        a.start_b()
        # Assertion Logic


def create_b_mock(self):
    b = mock.MagicMock(spec=B.B)
    b.start.side_effect = callback_method
    return b

def callback_method(self):
    self.callback(self)
```

Errors:
TypeError: callback_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0):

If your code is right, I mean, there is no indentation error, you are calling callback_method outside of class, with positional parameter `self`. This is the error.

If `callback_method` from **tests/test_A.py** should be inside class, you will receive an error that `unittest.TestCase` has not callback method.

Comment: but the create_b() method works correctly, and it is doing the same thing.